# Find IIS Application Pool not linked to an application via Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I would like to write a powershell script that will find all Application Pool on a server that are not link to an application and then delete the application pool that are not used.

One way I can think of doing this is to retrieve all the Application pool, retrieve all the IIS applications and then cross check the two list.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: That seems to the only way.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, here's the code I've written:

```
$UsedAppPoolList = get-item "IIS:\Sites\*" | foreach { $_.applicationPool; Get-WebApplication -Site $_.Name | foreach { $_.applicationPool } }
$AppPoolExistList = get-item 'IIS:\AppPools\*' | foreach { $_.Name }

foreach ( $AppPool in $AppPoolExistList ){
    if ($UsedAppPoolList -notcontains $AppPool){
        Remove-WebAppPool $AppPool
        write-host "Delete Application Pool $AppPool"
    }
}
```